# How do I make google chrome open a cached copy of unavailable pages automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

When I open a link to an unavailable page, I get the "Oops! Google Chrome could not find http://example.com" message and a link to open a cached copy to it. Is there any way (even if it is through an extension or app) for me to configure it to open the cached copy automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I use these methods for exactly this. But they don't open automatically.

This is an extension: [Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bnmfcdcicagaffaokphooddegagehcin).

[This is a bookmarklet.](http://javascript:void%28%28function%28%29%7Bvar%20a=location.href.replace%28/%5Ehttp%5C:%5C/%5C/%28.*%29$/,%22$1%22%29;location.href=%22http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:%22%20escape%28a%29;%7D%29%28%29%29)

Some more bookmarklets: [Coral](http://javascript:window.location%20=%20%22http://%22+window.location.hostname+%22.nyud.net%22+window.location.pathname), [Wayback](http://javascript:window.location%20=%20%22http://%22+window.location.hostname+%22.nyud.net%22+window.location.pathname).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm really not interested in anything that doesn't open automatically. I'm just trying to avoid the annoying extra click :P